# MySQL: Getting a specfied using subquerys with MAX() and COUNT()

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a specified attribute from a sub-query. What i want it's the id_prova (from the sub-query)  that relates to another table that holds the correspondent  value. How can i get it "out" from there so i can make the proper comparasings. I aprecciate any help.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  nome_Animal,
  id_prova,
  MAX(TotalAmount) 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    provas_animais.nome_Animal,
    provas.id_prova,
    SUM(montante) AS TotalAmount 
  FROM
    patrocinador_anologo,
    provas,
    provas_animais 
  WHERE patrocinador_anologo.id_prova = provas.id_prova 
    AND patrocinador_anologo.id_prova = provas_animais.id_prova 
  GROUP BY (provas.id_prova)) provas,
  provas_animais 
GROUP BY (id_prova)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to make your like below. What you are doing is getting data from a derived table (`FROM (...)`). I have as well change your join syntax to make it proper. Also, your last group by is not needed since you are just trying to get the maximum of `TotalAmount`.

```
Select nome_Animal, 
id_prova, 
MAX(TotalAmount) 
FROM 
(
select provas_animais.nome_Animal,
provas.id_prova, 
sum(montante) as TotalAmount 
FROM patrocinador_anologo
join provas on patrocinador_anologo.id_prova = provas.id_prova
join provas_animais on patrocinador_anologo.id_prova = provas_animais.id_prova

GROUP BY provas.id_prova
) X
```

Comment: The problem is that i keep getting this error: (Column 'nome_animal' in field list is ambiguos)

Comment: @user3716233, did you tried the query in my answer? Try it first.

Comment: Yes, we tried.

Also, i dont know how to use the data delivered by the table from the sub-query. What i want is the field "nome_Animal" after making the SUM of two fields(TotalAmount) in the table "patrocinador_anologo" and the table "patrocinador_oficial" which i forgot to post.

Comment: @user3716233, Just do `select * from (subquery)` to use the data delivered by the table from the sub-query. For your second part of question in comment which you forgot to post ... go ahead and post a new question for the same.